# How useful is entanglement entropy?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, entanglement-entropy

In thermodynamics, the entropy $S$ can be used to determine various physical quantities, i.e. the free energy, the temperature etc.

If I calculate the entanglement entropy of a system, is there some analogous quantities that I can derive? Do I know anything more about the full system than I did before, having calculated the entanglement entropy of some sub-system? (Other than the amount of entanglement between the subsystems)

Conceptually, what do I know if I have calculated the EE?

Comment: The entanglement between the parts of the system, given the total state is pure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, what does the entanglement entropy represent if the total system is in a mixed state?

Comment: @AndreaPaco If you have a new question you should ask a new question.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, well, in your previous comment you explained the meaning of EE specifying the assumption "given the total state is pure". I am curious to know the answer also in case the total state is mixed. Do you think that this issue deserve a stand-alone question? If so, no problem. Just let me know.

Comment: @AndreaPaco The vague answer is "it measures classical entropy of the subsystem, classical correlations with the other system, and entanglement".

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, thanks a lot for your kind answer. So, in conclusion, the EE relevant to a mixed state "mixes" the three contributes you've mentioned, i.e. classical entropy, classical correlations, and quantum entanglement?

Comment: @AndreaPaco Don't call it "entanglement entropy".  EE only applies to overall pure states.  It is just entropy, or von Neumann entropy.  Not sure where this new habit of calling it "entanglement entropy" comes from.

Comment: Thanks @NorbertSchuch. Since I guess that this issue deserves further investigation, I've created a new question. Please take a look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374446/von-neumann-entropy-of-pure-and-mixed-states in case you wish to deep or expand your kind answer. Thanks again.